# Laravel 4 Authentication does not work and gives NO ERROR

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-blade

I have been searching for solutions and changing my code back and forth but nothing worked for me and I honestly have given up hope to fix it by myself.
It stays on the same page and does not `Redirect::to('test2')`, but stays in the same page and when I remove the `else { return Redirect::to('login')`, it gives me a blank page. 
Any help would be extremely appreciated.

This is my user model file:

```
protected $fillable=['email', 'password'];

    protected $table = 'users';

    protected $hidden = array('password', 'remember_token');

    protected $primaryKey = 'id';

    public static $rules = array(
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'password' => 'required',
    );

    public function getAuthIdentifier()
    {
        return $this->getKey();
    }

    public function getAuthPassword()
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    public function getReminderEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }
```

This is my routing functions:

```
Route::get('/login', function(){
    return View::make('login');
});

Route::post('/login',  function(){
    $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), User::$rules);
    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return Redirect::to('login')
            ->withErrors($validator) 
            ->withInput(Input::except('password')); 
    } else {
        $userData = array(
            'email'     => Input::get('email'),
            'password'  => Input::get('password')
        );
        if (Auth::attempt($userData)) {
            return Redirect::to('test2');
            echo 'SUCCESS!';
        } else {
            return Redirect::to('login');
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is the password stored in your database hashed?

Comment: Yes it is hashed, and my table, and register form is working perfectly.

Comment: Is it possible that the password gets truncated? (The min length of the password column should be 60 characters)

Comment: I just tried many passwords, very long and also "unhashed" passwords, but same problem.

Comment: Can you try copying the hash from the database and do this: `Hash::check('your-password', 'the-hash-from-your-db')` If this returns true, the hash is correct.

Comment: I have a password mismatch, and even when I insert the same password twice, the hash is different, and when I compare it like you said (using my form password field and my 'hashed' password of the database) I also get a mismatch. @lukasgeiter
I'm sure I have a "Hash function" problem, but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Well it is normal that the hash function produces a new hash everytime (because it uses the current timestamp). Can you paste a hash from your db in here?

Comment: '1234' = '$2y$10$AOMFWl2CxHgY85P9K3w0ceZgPpJG35UUWXHnOeAnmRM' & '1234' also = '$2y$10$fRoyQRiTToZ7kye5mAWCQO0yr9kwyLjA0ZJbdayIigY'

Comment: And you did try `Hash:check('1234', '$2y$10$AOMFWl2CxHgY85P9K3w0ceZgPpJG35UUWXHnOeAnmRM')`?

Comment: Yes, but did not work... even tried Hash:check('$2y$10$AOMFWl2CxHgY85P9K3w0ceZgPpJG35UUWXHnOeAnmRM', '$2y$10$AOMFWl2CxHgY85P9K3w0ceZgPpJG35UUWXHnOeAnmRM')... nothing. Do you think something's wrong with the environment?

Comment: How about `Hash::check('1234', Hash::make('1234'))`?

Comment: Yes, this thing outputs true in an if statement `if (Hash::check('1234', Hash::make('1234')))` @lukasgeiter

Comment: Then the hash methods are working correctly. I still think the mistake happens when saving.

Comment: Can you output the hash you generate during registration and compare that to the one in the new db record?

Comment: I did something stupid I might quit programming for, which is that I forgot to make the 'password' field up to 60 characters... I realized that after a stupid while... Sorry and thanks for the help I should've made sure my field is 60 char when you said so...

Comment: Told you so :P No worries, and don't quit because of this. Remember learning means making mistakes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been struggling around with the hash at beginning.
1. If the length of your password column isn't 60 then it wouldn't allow you to login.
2. Before logging via Auth::attempt() instead try to fetch the data of the user using his username
and then compare the password using Hash::check()
try something this

```
  Route::post('/login',  function(){
  $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), User::$rules);
 if ($validator->fails()) {
    return Redirect::to('login')
        ->withErrors($validator) 
        ->withInput(Input::except('password')); 
 } else {

 $email=Input::get('email');
 $user=User::where('email','=',$email)->first();
 $bool=Hash::check('your password for the email',$user->password);
 if(bool)
    {
      if (Auth::attempt(Input::only('email','password')))
       {
          return Redirect::to('test2');
          echo 'SUCCESS!';
       }else{
         return Redirect::to('login');
       }
   }else{
    return echo 'password didn't matche';
  }
}
```